# Loop over array of items that implement an interface

Tags: go

Suppose I have an array of items that implement an interface `Reader`:

```
var items []Foo
```

How would I pass these items into a function that takes readers?

```
func (items []Reader) { ... }
```

I can't use the type `[]Reader` because I get an error like:

```
Cannot use type `[]Foo` as type `[]Reader`...
```

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface (and substitute `io.Reader` for `interface{}` when reading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

var items []*bytes.Buffer

func f(items []io.Reader) {}

func main() {
    readers := make([]io.Reader, len(items))
    for i, item := range items {
        readers[i] = item
    }
    f(readers)
}
```

Comment: That works, but it means I have to loop over all the items before I call the function. I was trying to avoid the loop.

Comment: @VladtheImpala: Because they do not have the same representation in memory, it is necessary to copy the elements individually. [`Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?`](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to peterSO's answer.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

type Foo struct{}
type Foos []Foo


func (f Foos) toReaders() []io.Reader {
    readers := make([]io.Reader, len(f))
    for i, item := range f {
        readers[i] = item
    }
    return  readers
}

func f(items []io.Reader) {}

func main() {
    var x Foos
    f(x.toReaders())
}
```